# Pygame TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: pygame

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))
cam.start()
image = cam.get_image()
```

---

That is what my code so far is..but I get this error....

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ghost/Desktop/Test", line 8, in <module>
    cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\_camera_vidcapture.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.dev = vidcap.new_Dev(device, show_video_window)
TypeError: an integer is required**
```

What have I done wrong in the code?  I am new to programming so I am not sure where to start

Comment: my guess would be that it expects an integer as the first parameter, not a string. Try it with 0

Comment: Could you clarify a little more?  I am not sure what you mean

Comment: Your call to camera.Camera should be `Camera(0,(640,480))`

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In my case.

edited code like this.

```
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))
↓
cam = pygame.camera.Camera(0,(640,480))
```

"/dev/video0" -> It mean Linux folder path